# How to plot density histogram for each chromosome reads in R

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics

I have this data file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/hei2fa25r9ezvkx/myfile.csv?dl=0

I want to plot a density plot for chr1 to chr16 start position. So I want to partition the X axes into chr1, chr2, chr3, ..chr16 and within each chr partition, I want to get the `density` plot for each start position. I want the `density` variable plotted on the Y axis. I have tried something like this mentioned [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/282966/#283036), but it does not divide the Y axes in each chr group and their respective start position in X axis. Can someone please help me plot this. Thanks!

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
inFn = args[1]
outFn = args[2]
title = args[3]
xRange <- range(0, d$stop) 
yRange <- range(0, d$density)
pdf(outFn)
plot(xRange, yRange, type="l", xlab="Position", ylab="Density", main=title)
lines(d$start, d$density)
dev.off()
```

Updated with the reproducible data:

```
d<- structure(list(chr = c("chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr10", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", 
"chr3", "chr3", "chr3"), start = c(6, 14, 19, 24, 8442, 8446, 
8487, 8489, 8491, 8497, 13282, 13324, 13325, 13328, 13366, 13368
), stop = c(6, 14, 19, 24, 8442, 8446, 8487, 8489, 8491, 8497, 
13282, 13324, 13325, 13328, 13366, 13368), density = c(10, 4, 
1, 3, 9, 62, 43, 115, 419, 2, 982, 57, 14, 248, 16, 1)), .Names = c("chr", 
"start", "stop", "density"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6000L, 
6001L, 6002L, 6003L, 6004L, 6005L, 10000L, 10001L, 10002L, 10003L, 
10004L, 10005L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

From time to time I have to plot data like this and I always use `geom_point`. `geom_bar` is too stacked and `geom_line` looks bad if there are gaps in the chromosome (ie., centromere).

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(start, density)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.9) +
    facet_grid(. ~ chr) +
    labs(title = "Density profiles along the chromosomes",
         x = "Coordinate, bp",
         y = "Density") +
    theme_bw()
```

You can use `facet_grid(. ~ chr, scales = "free")` which "zooms" into a specific region in each chromosome.

[image]

Comment: @MAPK can I improve my answer in any way?